# SQL injection even when the variable is escaped

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

The sql injection will work only when my query looks like below sample

```
SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = $my_id_va;
```

Assume if my query is

```
SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = $my_id_va ORDER BY id DESC
```

Than I will get following error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order by id desc' at line 1

So, this `1 or 1=1; SHOW TABLES` will not work, correct?

My site was hacked successively many times.

I want one quick answer: *When my query looks like the following one, what ways or which types of query can they use to hack my site?*

```
SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = $my_id_va ORDER BY id DESC
```

What are the ways to  execute the `show table` in the following query

```
SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = $my_id_va ORDER BY id DESC
```

I am  also using escaping function to handle the query string values, like `mysql_real_escape_string($my_id_va)`. Yes, obviously this for single related hack, but not sure.

Added some more

```
SELECT EventActuallyCharged, EventDate FROM tblevent WHERE EventDate between '2011-07-21 or 1=1; SHOW TABLES --' and '2011-07-31' ORDER BY EventDate DESC
```

but show table not worked

Comment: You want us to teach you how to hack, or how to protect? You are already using `mysql_real_escape_string($my_id_va)` which will escape all special characters to protect you against most of the attacks. The harm will be almost zero. If you want to be sure 100%, then use PDO or MySQLi. However, this kind of question smells bad to me.

Comment: @Shef: sorry thing is, i am facing cont prob even i used these mysql_real_escape_string everything, your question makes me angry, i dont, i should proceed my issue furtheir, else shall i stop posting question, your comment is really hurting, i got good sug from GolezTrol, domanokz, Mark Byers, Zach R, but you only thinging like bad, sorry for comment

Comment: I see you commenting everywhere _"why the `SHOW TABLES` is not working?"_ Are you interested in it NOT working, or working? What do you want?

Comment: i should want to know, what are the neg ways available to execute this show table, so that i can understand, this manner also others will try for hacking. somthing like, ok cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that `1 or 1=1; SHOW TABLES` will give a syntax error but this will work:

```
1 or 1=1 --
```

The -- comments out the rest of the query.

In your case the value is an integer so instead of using `mysql_real_escape_string` you can use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Comment: check my update, show table not worked, but regular query worked as usual

Comment: @bharanikumar Bs: You can't use `SHOW TABLE` there. Just use `1 or 1=1 --`. That will fetch all rows from the table.

Comment: so if use the mysql_real_escape_string, than 1 or 1=1 -- this malicious will not work know

Comment: @bharanikumar Bs: Yes it will, because you didn't quote it. Use intval, like I said in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP5, use parametarized query, use PDO.

Answer (score 2):

**Int cast**

If `id` is a number, you can int-cast your variable as well. Integers are safe to use:

```
$x = (int)$yourInputVar;
$s = "select * from Table where id = $x";
```

**mysql_real_escape_string**

If you want to pass a string, you can, and should, use `mysql_real_escape_string`, but this function escapes only those characters that are inside the string. You will still need to add quotes around the string, so:

```
 $x = mysql_real_escape_string('hello');
 $s = "select * from Table where id = $x";
```

.. will result in the query: `select * from Table where id = hello`. This is obiously not a valid query, since hello should be in quotes.

Change the query to:

```
 $x = mysql_real_escape_string('hello');
 $s = "select * from Table where id = '$x'";
```

.. and everything works fine. You add the quotes around, and `mysql_real_escape_string` takes care of special characters inside the string, if any.

**Parameters**

Another solution is to use parameterized queries. This can by done using MySQLi or PDO. The advantage is that you only tell your database where a variable should be inserted, and the database takes care of the escaping yourself.

It also may add a performance benefit, because these queries could be cached without their parameters, make a more efficient use of the query cache. This doesn't really work yet in current versions of MySQL, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `$my_id_va` to:

`1 or 1=1; SHOW TABLES --`

The `--` will comment out the rest of the command, effectively terminating it.

I'm not sure what effect `mysql_real_escape_string` will have on the query.  What you should be doing is [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. First query somehow secured

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = %d ORDER BY id DESC', mysql_real_escape_string($my_id_va));
```

#### 2. Second query somehow secured

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT EventActuallyCharged, EventDate FROM tblevent WHERE EventDate BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' ORDER BY EventDate DESC", 
             mysql_real_escape_string($start_date),
             mysql_real_escape_string($end_date));
```

---

Read the docs about [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) if you don't understand it.

However, as others have said, it would be very very secure if you would use parameterized queries with a class such as [**PDO**](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**MySQLi**](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).